# Probability mass function meeting the expectation of distributions of independent Bernoulli variables

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Suppose there are $n$ objects that have probabilities $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n$ of being selected, respectively. The sum of these probabilities is not necessarily $1$. Also assume that the first $k < n$ objects form a "special" group. If with probability $\rho$, you must select an object from that group and with probability $1 - \rho$ you must select an object from the entire group, how do you work out the probability mass function that allows you to sample exactly $m$ different items such that in expectation, object $i$ appears in $p_i$ of the samples?

My application is to the following situation.
I have an adjacency-like matrix for generating (simple) undirected graphs, where each entry is a probability stating what proportion of graphs have the corresponding edge in their edge sets. I have identified a set of edges $E'$ not in a given graph $G = (V, E)$ that I will "treat differently" compared to the entire set of edges not in $G$ (the set $E(K_{|V|}) \setminus E$, where $K$ is for complete graphs).

I want to add some decided number of edges from $E'$ and another decided number of edges where the entire set of edges not (already) in $E$ are candidates. The ratio of these two numbers is $\rho$. The frequency for the edges in $E'$ should equal their entries in the matrix.

Comment: I cannot clearly understand what you are asking here.  Apparently the problem is "work out the probability mass function" so that objects will be sampled with specified frequency (object *i* will appear in $p_i$ of the samples), but neither the "special" group nor the application to generating undirected graphs is clear to me.  Perhap an example of modest size, say $n=5$ with special subset of $3$ objects, would clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: @hardmath: Now that I think about it, I think there's no need to mention $m$. If I have $n$ independent random variables with binomial distribution, how do I sample so that the proportion of times object $i$ is selected is $p_i$?

Comment: Okay, but before $m$ was the size of the sample you would select.  Are you saying now you want only to select one object (sample size $1$), or are you thinking of some other schema with "no need to mention $m$"?

Comment: I haven't taken probability and statistics and think that I misused the word "sample" at the end of the first paragraph. If I sample $m$ different items each time (say, for each new graph) and take $M$ samples, then there are $mM$ items sampled and I expect to see object $i$ appear $p_iM$ times. I guess when I first thought about this problem, I was distracted by how I know the number of trials to perform (each time)... So now it wouldn't matter how many objects there are to select, so long as the pmf is right - am I right?

Comment: Let me try to give a sketch of how a randomized graph might be chosen, and you can advise whether that setup meets your needs.